# How to write a range of symbols in LaTeX in a loop

Tags: latex

I need to generate a large ammount of mathematical symbols in LaTeX to use in a database.
Is there a way to write from character X to character Y?

For example, I could write this in C to print characters from A to Z:

```
char c, start_char = 'A', end_char = 'Z';
for(c = start_char; c <= end_char; c++) {
    printf("%c\n", c);
}
```

Can I do something similar to write a large list of symbols in LaTeX? For example, from \alpha to \theta
I know I could write a list from scratch, but it would be a biiiiiiiig list...

Comment: Ok big list...but what characters? All the ASCII ones or what? :)

Comment: @MattAllegro any kind, but specially mathematical ones, like greek letters, operators special symbols, notations, functions...